# Is there a way to add padding to a UICollectionView cell programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image: my UICollectionView UI]

I would like to know how to add padding to cells within a collection view. In the image above, you can see that the shadow of the cell is being cut off where the table view ends(see black arrow).

I am fairly new to Swift programming, so a thorough explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method - optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

Answer (score 0):

You can set collectionView `sectionInset` in this way:

```
private let spacing:CGFloat = 16.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Hope this will help you.

For more, you can see this: https://medium.com/@NickBabo/equally-spaced-uicollectionview-cells-6e60ce8d457b